# Google Forms Script Reset & Update Style

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to write a script that will delete all responses, start a new sheet and then style the new sheet by making the first row red color.  Here is what I have so far:

```
function Initialize2() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId()); 
  form.deleteAllResponses();
  form.removeDestination();
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
  form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId()); 

  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z1");
  range.setBackground("red");
  sheet.setFrozenColumns(1);
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that it will create a new sheet, but the color update happens on the previously active sheet.  How do I make it so that it updates the new active sheet?

Comment: @404 SpreadsheetApp.flush(); did the trick, can you post it as an answer and I'll mark as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you select a sheet for color changes, the new sheet with form responses may not exist yet, because Sheets [may postpone operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) to improve performance. To ensure the creation has happened, call

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

before

```
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
```